# Use recipient address as sender address when replying to a message in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

My Thunderbird is setup with 3 email accounts - one to receive and send everything (Gmail, since it's secure) and two which are my personal and work emails.

The problem is that, whenever I reply to a message Thunderbird selects my Gmail address in the "From" field, so I need to change it either my personal of work email depending on who I reply to.

So I'm looking for a way to have the sender address to be put in the "From" field whenever I reply to an email. Let's say, someone send me an email to my personal address, when I reply to this email, my personal address should be selected in the "From" field (and ditto for my work email).

Do you know if it's possible to do this with Thunderbird? Or maybe is there some plugin? I searched for one but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is actually how (recent versions of) Thunderbird operate by default.  Each account's default identity is linked to the mailbox that is picked up via IMAP/POP.  You've *changed* from the default, per your description.

Furthermore, adding multiple identities to the Google Mail account will cause Thunderbird to [pick the appropriate identity automatically when composing replies](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mozilla_Suite_:_FAQs_:_Mail_Aliases) in that account.  There's even a configuration option that tells it to pick identities from other accounts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked after I've added the identities to the Google Mail account.