# How to copy the recipient address into the reply-to field automatically when replying to email in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, reply

**Problem**:

I've been using a CATCHALL alias on my domains for quite some time. And up until now, I've had to type the email-address which I want the recipient to respond to, manually, in thunderbird.

**Workflow**:
For the purpose of this question, I will use the fictional domain `earth.io`.

I have configured my email server to drop any emails sent to any address on the domain earth.io to `junk@earth.io` *the CATCHALL*, so if you send an email to `xfvy123@earth.io`, it will arrive in `junk@earth.io`.

Now, in the past I've handed out unregistered email-addresses *like* `xfvy123@earth.io` to people and businesses I want to keep in touch with. For example, I gave Noah Bennett the address `noah.bennet@earth.io`, and I gave Hiro Nakamura the address `hiro.nakamura@earth.io`. I do this so I can distinguish them from the crowd and also keep track of who and what has obtained these addresses - and potentially, to sort out those who sent me something worth reading.

> The same goes for businesses and services, my social network accounts are registered using `social.face@earth.io`, `social.tweet@earth.io` and so on.

If emails are sent to the addresses mentioned, they end up in the inbox of `junk@earth.io`.

My *reply from* address is `from@earth.io`, I use this to write to people, complain about products and so on. I also use it to reply to those emails sent to my `junk@earth.io` address.

> Note: The address `from@earth.io` is an registered email account, similar to the `junk@earth.io` one, only difference is that it isn't used as CATCHALL address.

So, in Thunderbird, if I recieve an email from Hiro Nakamura, I will click reply, then change the *reply to* field to `hiro.nakamura@earth.io` type my reply and send it back to the recepient - now in the hopes that when they reply, they do so to the *reply to* address.

**Question**:

How can I have thunderbird copy the *to* address to the *reply to* field? Or somehow do it in an other way?

I've looked around here on superuser, but haven't found any answers to this issue. There is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/325254/use-recipient-address-as-sender-address-when-replying-to-a-message-in-thunderbir) but the answer is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Please use the terminology of Thunderbird : Accounts and identities. Your setup description is not clear.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. The place from where the image is taken, is called ´Account Settings´, and the form legend is named ´Defaul Identity´.

Comment: "I gave person A the address..." : Is this an identity? etc. You may show instead more screenshots if you prefer. I may be able to guess what you mean, but I prefer being sure before answering.

Comment: I see what you mean now. No, you can assume that only emails@mydomain.tld is an identity. Any other address, like ´personC@mydomain.tld´ are dummies that I invent on the spot, when I hand them out. They are not registered anywhere, and I will not use them to send emails from. Only have them automatically added as a "reply-to" address when I hit reply in Thunderbird from people who have sent me emails **to** these addresses I've given them.

Comment: I don't think that such a solution exists any longer. There were a handful of extensions written for that, but they are all now incompatible with Thunderbird 68. Their source code is still available if this interests you. I tested a couple and the old trick of increasing `maxVersion` in `install.rdf` is no longer enough, so more development is required. I use instead [e4ward](http://e4ward.com/) for creating temporary addresses - this avoids having a long list of identities and also avoids spam (for which catch-all is very vulnerable), and it has a good UI.

Comment: First, you need a mail server which is willing to record the recipient mail address into a specific header (this is not normally the case). Then you need to instruct Thunderbird to use this mail address as sender address.

Comment: @Lazio Valko: Say I have these capabilities on my mail server. How would you go about instructing Thunderbird to use this email as reply-to address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is built into Thunderbird for a while now.

[Screenshot example of Account Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsoOp.png)

1. Go to `Account Settings`
2. Enable `Reply from this identity when delivery headers match`
3. Enter your domain prefixed by a wildcard (`*`), for example `*@yourdomain.com`
4. Close/confirm all your changes
5. Open an email that was sent to one of your catch-all addresses and click the reply button.
6. The FROM field should be the catch-all address and not your general address.

Comment: This is the currently working answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this extension:

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/reply-as-original-recipient/

It's dealing with the `From:` header, not the `Reply-to:`, but I think it's not far from what you're looking for.

Comment: "Works with Thunderbird 17.0 - 64". Current version is 68.

Comment: Close, but this extension wont work with the new API, even if I change the version check to 68. I even tried to work it a bit. But I won't be going down to 64 just to make this work.

Comment: you're right, I didn't pay attention version compatibility.. Didn't found any relevant possiblity, Neither with Evolution mail. I know it's feasible with the mutt client, but it might be off-topic as you mentioned a graphical mail client in the first place.

Comment: This was a pickle for me, I don't want to waste the 50 points, but I don't want to have them be consumed either. I will give you the points since you have the least, and give Harry the answer points.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that such a solution exists any longer.

There were a handful of extensions written for that, 
such as Virtual Identity and Reply As Original Recipient,
but they are all now incompatible with Thunderbird 68.
Their source code is still available if this interests you:
[absorb-it/Virtual-Identity](https://github.com/absorb-it/Virtual-Identity)
and
[qiqitori/reply_as_original_recipient](https://github.com/qiqitori/reply_as_original_recipient).

I tested the above extensions, and the old trick of increasing `maxVersion`
in the installation file `install.rdf` is no longer enough, the extension
stays incompatible with Thunderbird 68.

An easier solution is to use a web service that creates aliases,
such as [e4ward](http://e4ward.com/) for creating temporary or permanent
addresses and to avoid having a long list of identities.
E4ward allocates aliases, which look like `alias@username.e4ward.com`. I give out these aliases, and E4ward forwards emails sent to them to my real email address, but with a tricked return address that I can use to respond such that my answer would seem to come from the alias.

The advantages of this method are :

- Avoids spam for which catch-all is very vulnerable. An address that leaks
  and starts being spammed can be deleted and replaced.
- Everything is automatic. The From and Reply-to are automatically the same,
  so no possibility of the user wrongly replying to the wrong address.
- Flexibility for email changes: If ever `mydomain.tld` is changed to
  `newdomain.tld`, then all identities must change and all users must be
  notified and can no longer Reply to existing conversations.
  With web-aliases like E4ward, a small change on the E4ward website is enough,
  and the change is seamless from the client's point of view.

Comment: what is a "tricked return address"?

Comment: I didn't delete anything... however, I don't yet see the benefit in using a webservice, does it takes me less time than creating an identity in Thunderbird (as I suggested in my answer - see second work around)?

Comment: I wish the extension documentation for Thunderbird just had been more comprehensible. It is hard to make sense of their new API. Unfortunately, I do not want to use online services like e4ward.

Comment: @Elmo: I have been using e4ward for years and they have been absolutely trustworthy and dependable and immediately reacting to problems. If you don't prefer to create your own extension, this solution is certain to do the job.

Comment: I appreciate that you suggest this online service, both here and in previous answers, I understand that you find them trustworthy. But I am not comfortable with services like this and on top of that, there is a monthly fee if you cannot stay within the limits of the free account. Their limits are not satisfactory for me, and I do not want to pay for a service like this either. As a last concern, I don't know where they originate. If it is US any other benefits would be void in any case. I still thank you for the contribution though.

Comment: I [pay](http://help.e4ward.com/buynow.html) 12$ per year, but mostly because I feel bad about not contributing, as the free account is quite generous for email.

Comment: I think that these are really guidelines for donations, because I never had e4ward prompt me to pay or encountered a cap on my email.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically, without an addon, this is not possible. Mainly because replying as the address in the "to-field" is not a regular use case for Thunderbird (since you could have receive the email via CC or BCC as well).

However, there as a simple simple workarounds using the `From-Field` instead of the `Reply-To-Field`:

**First workaround:** you can chooce `user defined sender`, then it's just type it in or use copy and paste:

[image]

You just click on the `from` field, there you can add any other adress. Make sure the account you create to send out the email is allowed to use any email adress from your domain.

**A second work around** would be to create another identity within your for each email adress you pass out. It usually is selected automatically by Thunderbird when you reply to an answer to this address.

**As a third work around**, expanding on Saïmonn's answer, you could just install an old version of Thunderbird e.g. [Version 60.9.0](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/60.9.0/releasenotes/) (the last stable one before V68 - [see here for all versions](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/releases/)). This way you could still install an [addon that allows you to reply as the recipient](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/reply-as-original-recipient/). Beware of potential security risks using outdated software. Unless you know what you are doing it's always a good idea to sandbox it e.g. with [sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/).

PS. sorry for the German screen shot

Comment: None of your suggestions are satisfactory, what you suggest are exactly what I try to avoid.

Comment: @Elmo well, yeah, unfortunately that's the problem with workarounds... maybe it will help s.o. else. Anyway, glad your problem was solved.